# Kaye Exercise 6.4.2 Classical Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, textbook-and-exercises, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

Can anyone help with this problem from, An Introduction to Quantum
Computing, Phillip Kaye, Raymond Laflamme, Michele Mosca

Exercise 6.4.2: Show that a probabilistic classical algorithm that makes $O(n)$ queries can with probability at least $1 − \frac{1}{2^n}$ correctly determine whether $f$ is constant or balanced.

Hint: Use the Chernoff bound (Appendix A.1).

I am new to Quantum Computing and deutsch jozsa problem, and Hint is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following algorithm:

**1.** Choose $n+1$ bitstrings $\{q_1,\dots,q_{n+1}\}\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ uniformly at random (allowing repetitions). 
**2.** If $f(q_1)=\dots=f(q_{n+1})$ return "*CONSTANT*" 
**3.** Else return "*BALANCED*"

Now let's analyze the above algorithm. If $f$ is constant then the algorithm will always be correct. If on the other side $f$ is balanced then the probability that our algorithm will return *CONSTANT* is bounded by the probability
$$\tag{1}\mathbb{P}\left(f(q_1)=f(q_2), f(q_1)=f(q_3), \dots, f(q_1)=f(q_{n+1})\right).$$
The $n$ events $f(q_1)=f(q_i)$ are independent and have probability of occurring equal to $\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}$ (since out of the $2^n$ possible bitstrings there are $\frac{2^{n}}{2}=2^{n-1}$ that  yield the same value of $f$ as $f(q_1)$ and thus the probability of error is at most $\frac{1}{2^n}$, as required. Notice that the Chernoff bound was not used here.

Basically, each of the events in Eq. 1 of this answer will occur with a probability of 1/2, and there are $n$ such events, so the overall probability will be $1/2^n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate in your answer on how you get the bound? Also how does Chernov ineq come into play?

Comment: @MonteNero I have edited my answer to explain a bit more how the probability of error was derived. Is it ok now?