# How does Chernoff's bound help to solve Exercise 6.4.2 in Kaye et al.'s textbook?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, probability, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this question, I'm kind of new to quantum computing in general. I understand the Deutsch Josza Algorithm, but I'm not really sure where to even begin with question 6.4.2 from [An Introduction to Quantum Computing](https://batistalab.com/classes/v572/Mosca.pdf).

> **Exercise 6.4.2:** Show that a probabilistic classical algorithm that
> makes $()$ queries can with probability at least
> $1−\frac{1}{2^}$ correctly determine whether  is constant or
> balanced.
>
> Hint: Use the Chernoff bound (Appendix A.1).

---

I have taken a look at the answer to [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27775/25170) question. However, it does not use Chernoff bound to arrive at the answer. I am looking for an answer that makes use of Chernoff bound.

Comment: See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27775/9474)

Comment: @Egretta.Thula why didn't you vote to close it as a duplicate?

Comment: @user1271772Nomorefreetime thanks for linking that, I saw it earlier but wanted to ask again but with using the Chernoff bound as part of the explanation

Comment: If you saw that question, why didn't you provide a link to it in your question; and also why did you not ask: "How can the Chernoff bound be used to arrive at the expression 1 - 1/2^n in this problem?". By not doing those two things, if it weren't for @Egretta.Thula luckily being there to save the day, someone might have wasted their time writing down the same answer that was already written in the past, and still you wouldn't have your answer using the Chernoff bound.